# Does the convergence of a matrix iteration imply convergence of the matrix entries?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say I know that
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\mathbf{A}^k\mathbf{x=x}^*\,.
$$
Does it then follow that each of the entries $a_{i,j}^{(k)}$of $\mathbf{A}^k$ converge to a limit?

Comment: Does the limit hold for just one specific $x$ or for all $x$?

Comment: It only holds for at least one pair $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}^*$. Though I might be able to guarantee that $\mathbf{A}$ is invertible.

Comment: I can guarantee the existence of a pair where $\mathbf{x}$ isn't the zero vector.

Comment: No, the $x$ may lie in the kernel of $A$ but $A$ may be unbounded, for example.

Comment: This is true if and only if this holds for a system of $n$ linearly independent vectors.